# Custom Artisan Command in localhost

Tags: php, laravel, command, localhost, laravel-artisan

It is a Laravel project. I have my development host on Windows machine (XAMPP) and production/testing host on Ubuntu (Digital Ocean). When I run my command on my localhost it doesn't complain but nothing happens. The same command on production server works like a charm. Logic of command involves a lot of functions about creating HTTP requests, getting responses and saving them in the database. Database connections are proper at both sides.
Any ideas? 
Thanks!

**Simplified Command File**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\PageEngagedUsers;


class MinuteTasks extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'tasks:min';

    protected $description = 'Does One-Minute Tasks';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->Update();
    }

    public function Update()
    {
        $allPages = Page::all();

        foreach ($allPages as $page) {
            try {    
                        $curl = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://someurl.com/info?fields=values&featire=1&token=' . $page->token,
                            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
                        ));
                        $response = curl_exec($curl);
                        curl_close($curl);

                        \Log::info($response);
                        \Log::info(json_encode($response));

                        $obj = json_decode($response);
                        $value = $obj->{'data'}[0]->{'values'}[1]->value;

                        $pageEngagedUsers = new PageEngagedUsers;
                        $pageEngagedUsers->value = $value;

                        $page->pageEngagedUsers()->save($pageEngagedUsers);

                        }
                  catch (\Exception $e) {

                  }
        }
    }

}
```

**Log**

```
local.INFO:
local.INFO: false
```

`\Log::info($response)` gives nothing.
`\Log::info(json_encode($response))` gives false.

Comment: Checked the log?

Comment: Have some variables that contain path used? Windows uses backslashes. Although errors should be in log file.

Comment: Thanks for answers! If you mean storage\logs logfile, it doesn't show anything related to running that command. I mean it doesn't log this action at all. @Tpojka No, there are no paths used.

Comment: Clear log file and test again. You can put `\Log::info("Artisan command executed.");` at beginning of method and check if it is stored in log.

Comment: @Tpojka Yes, it was logged. No errors tho.

Comment: Then post your Artisan file code. Problem must be there.

Comment: @Tpojka added the code. Could it be some curl problem?

Comment: You missed main thing which could help you debugging the error. In catch block set `\Log::info($e->getMessage());`. Clear log file before that and made another call.

Comment: @Tpojka Thanks! Log says "Trying to get property of non-object", so it seems to really be a curl problem. I tried to log the response but it outputs nothing.

Comment: Remove all code after `curl_close` in try block and log `$response` or `json_encode($response)` (if first not working). Response has to be something but probably it's structure is not well accessed/handled in next lines. And if still an issue, edit your question with posted `$response` if possible.

Comment: @Tpojka Tried and edited my questions. Thanks.

Comment: Also try with al code removed after `curl_close()` function. Leave just logging without actual action that should be taken from curl response. Try to solve one thing at a time. Test API request/response with Postman (or browser; suggestion is to use Postman always): what this link give you outside the Laravel, hardcode values and check ( `https://someurl.com/info?fields=values&featire=1&token=' . $page->token` ).